# iOS UITests - How to distinguish two different XCUIElement?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xcode-ui-testing

While iOS UITesting, how can I distinguish between two different `XCUIElement`?

For example I have two different `UIButton` with same label string "Button". How to check they are different? Do `XCUIElement` provides ID or any distinct property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `accessibilityIdentifier` to each button in your app's code and access each button by its identifier in your tests to tell them apart. Accessibility identifiers are not user-facing, even to Accessibility users, so this will not affect your user experience.

```
// app code
buttonA.accessibilityIdentifier = "buttonA"
buttonB.accessibilityIdentifier = "buttonB"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let buttonA = app.buttons["buttonA"]
let buttonB = app.buttons["buttonB"]
```